# How to overcome this error in Xpath

Tags: r, xpath

I tried to extract the Holders table ("Direct Holders (Forms 3 and 4)") for FB.I copied the `Xpath` function by using Chrome's "Inspect element" for the table but I keep getting the error below.How can I solve this error?

```
url  = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/holders?p=FB"
doc = htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)
tab_nodes = xpathApply(doc, "//*[@id="main-0-Quote-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/section/div/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/table")
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "tab_nodes = xpathApply(doc, "//*[@id="main"

Comment: One way is to switch to single quotes around the entire xpath string instead of the double quotes, which are causing the issue because double quotes are used within the xpath.

Comment: Thanks @Jota for your answer. I'm getting NULL for tab_nodes.Maybe something else in the XPath is wrong.

Comment: Try this xpath `//*[@id='main-0-Quote-Proxy']//table`

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh Gaur,The use of your line (after changing ' to " ) gives me : list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"

Comment: So it's working or not??

Comment: No.I'm looking to get the table content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't scrape it since it's dynamic content built from data retrieved in an XHR request. While you have Developer Tools open, move to the Network tab, select "XHR" and refresh the page. You'll see a few URLs, one will be the data you need in JSON.

```
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

URL <- "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/FB?lang=en-US&region=US&modules=institutionOwnership%2CfundOwnership%2CmajorDirectHolders%2CmajorHoldersBreakdown%2CinsiderTransactions%2CinsiderHolders%2CnetSharePurchaseActivity&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com"
res <- GET(URL)
dat <- content(res)
df <- map_df(dat$quoteSummary$result[[1]]$majorDirectHolders$holders, ~as.list(unlist(.)))
glimpse(df)
## Observations: 10
## Variables: 22
## $ maxAge                   <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
## $ name                     <chr> "KOUM JAN", "SANDBERG SHERYL", "ZUCKERBERG MAR...
## $ relation                 <chr> "Director", "Officer", "Officer", "Officer", "...
## $ url                      <chr> "http://biz.yahoo.com/t/28/9464.html", "http:/...
## $ transactionDescription   <chr> "Automatic Sale", "Sale", "Automatic Sale", "A...
## $ latestTransDate.raw      <int> 1471824000, 1471219200, 1471478400, 1471219200...
## $ latestTransDate.fmt      <date> 2016-08-22, 2016-08-15, 2016-08-18, 2016-08-1...
## $ positionDirect.raw       <int> 2576396, 4593776, NA, 651044, 648776, 420525, ...
## $ positionDirect.fmt       <dbl> 2.58, 4.59, NA, 651.04, 648.78, 420.52, 222.19...
## $ positionDirect.longFmt   <dbl> 2576396, 4593776, NA, 651044, 648776, 420525, ...
## $ positionDirectDate.raw   <int> 1447632000, 1471219200, NA, 1471219200, 143164...
## $ positionDirectDate.fmt   <date> 2015-11-16, 2016-08-15, NA, 2016-08-15, 2015-...
## $ positionIndirect.raw     <int> 38729593, 23824, 3756744, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2144...
## $ positionIndirect.fmt     <dbl> 38.73, 23.82, 3.76, NA, NA, NA, NA, 214.41, 17...
## $ positionIndirect.longFmt <dbl> 38729593, 23824, 3756744, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2144...
## $ positionIndirectDate.raw <int> 1471824000, 1444348800, 1471478400, NA, NA, NA...
## $ positionIndirectDate.fmt <date> 2016-08-22, 2015-10-09, 2016-08-18, NA, NA, N...
## $ positionSummary.raw      <int> 41305989, 4617600, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 218185,...
## $ positionSummary.fmt      <dbl> 41.31, 4.62, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 218.19, 185.3...
## $ positionSummary.longFmt  <dbl> 41305989, 4617600, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 218185,...
## $ positionSummaryDate.raw  <int> 1471824000, 1471219200, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14...
## $ positionSummaryDate.fmt  <date> 2016-08-22, 2016-08-15, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2...
```

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr,I got this error , any help would be greate:"Parsed with column specification:cols(.default = col_integer(),  name = col_character(),  relation = col_character(),url = col_character(),transactionDescription = col_character(),  latestTransDate.fmt = col_date(format = ""),
  positionDirect.fmt = col_character(),  positionDirect.longFmt = col_number(),positionDirectDate.fmt = col_date(format = ""),
  positionIndirect.fmt = col_character(),positionIndirect.longFmt = col_number(),positionIndirectDate.fmt = col_date(format = ""),
 ..)See spec(...) for full column specifications."

Comment: try it without the `type_convert`. it worked fine on another system just now for me

Comment: Thanks a lot @hrbrmstr, I added the library 'dplyr' so glimpse function can work and removed the unneeded code line.

Comment: Another question if I may @hrbrmstr, Is there any good source to learn this kind of data extraction?